(seemingly) equivalent transformations of my Haskell code not working
I try to learn Haskell and struggle with converting do-syntax into monads.
So, I boiled it down to a tiny example.
I got this:
work :: String
work = do
    let arr = ["Get", "this", "to", "work"]
    let s = unlines arr
    s

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn work

And I rephrase it to:
work :: String
work = ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= unlines >>= return

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn work

Which gave me:
monad-do.hs:2:42: error:  
    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’  
      Expected type: [Char] -> [Char]  
        Actual type: [String] -> String  
    • In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘unlines’  
      In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely  
        ‘["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= unlines’  
      In the expression:  
        ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= unlines >>= return  
  |  
2 | work = ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= unlines >>= return  
  |                                          ^^^^^^^  

After figuring out what the error message tried to tell me, I got this working:
work :: String
work = ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= (\arr -> unlines [arr]) >>= return

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn work

Why do I need to pass [arr] instead of arr to unlines?

Why are you using monadic composition at all in a function that has a non-monadic type? Have you tried writing work without monads?

Are you intending to use the list monad here?

Look at the type of unlines and the type of arr.

Function unlines takes a list of strings.  And you can also use, within the list monad:  work = ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= (unlines . return)

@jpmarinier: I think that is exactly the point of my misconception: I thought ["Get"...] is of type [String]. And I would expect this to be passed to unlines, which should work.

@Seven What do you mean by passed to. And why do you think you need a monadic bind for that rather than function composition (the . operator)?

@NaïmFavier: I have. unlines takes [String]. arr seems to be [Char] which is String. But why? I thought I pass an Array of Strings to unlines.

No, you bound an array of Strings to unlines (using (>>=)). Look at the type of (>>=).

@NaïmFavier: Oh. So: Array is a Monad itself. >>= unpackages it to single Strings. This would mean, in my last (working) version, unlines would be called four times? Each time with an array containing a single String?

@user1937198: The nature of experiments with a new language is -- not to have any sense at all. Sure I could do this in a dozend of other ways. The category of question is not "how do I do this or that", but "I think this should work, why not?"

In general:
do
   foo <- bar
   ...

translates without do notation to bar >>= \ foo -> ...
and
do
  let foo = bar
  ...

translates to let foo = bar in do ....  These are not the same: only <- translates to a >>=.  <- has a very different meaning in do notation than let.
You have ignored this in your translation.

Just for reference, https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14 provides the identities you can use to translate do expressions.

I think I found my misunderstanding.
I completely missed out the mechanics of "unpacking" Monads to plain types and "repacking" plain types to Monadic types again.
(In the example I also adjusted the return type of work to deliver a Monad (i.e. Maybe String) instead of a plain type, which makes more sense)
So, I now have this version (with annotations what is going on), which is basically what I originally wanted to try:
work :: Maybe String
work = Just ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= (\arr -> Just (unlines arr))          >>= (\s -> return s)
--     ^    ^                               ^   ^      ^     ^                        ^   ^    ^
--     |    |                               |   |      |     +-- (5) returns ::String |   |    |
--     |    |                               |   |      +-- (6) to  ::Maybe String     |   |    |
--     |    |                               |   |                                     |   |    +-- (9) "packs" ::String into  ::Maybe String
--     |    +-- (1) ::[String]              |   +-- (4) ::[String]                    |   +-- (8) ::String
--     |                                    |                                         +-- (7) "unpacks" ::Maybe String  to ::String
--     |                                    +-- (3) "unpacks" ::Maybe [String]   to ::[String]
--     +-- (2) "packs" ::[String] into  ::Maybe [String]
--
--
-- Which then can be simplyfied via these steps
--
--work = Just ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= (\arr -> Just (unlines arr)) >>= (\s -> return s)
--work = Just ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= (\arr -> Just (unlines arr)) >>= return
--work = Just ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= Just . unlines               >>= return
--work = Just ["Get", "this", "to", "work"] >>= Just . unlines


main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn (fromMaybe "" work)

